# Can't compile a HHP into CHM using HHC.EXE with Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: msbuild, chm, visual-studio-2017, custom-build-step, html-help

OK, I know this is for Visual Studio 6 but I have been able to compile CHM files from within Visual Studio for years:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733976(v=vs.60).aspx

Now, on 2017 RC, I am having problems.

The Html Help folder is available:

[image: Executable folders]

So that bit is OK.

I have set the HHP file  to compile to a CHM:

[image: Custom settings]

Yet, when I try to compile the HHP file I get this error:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017rc\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3021,7):
>   error MSB4057: The target "CoreCompile" does not exist in the project.

I am really stumped. I have tweaked and tweaked it and I can't build my HHP file using this method. At the moment I have to manually open it using **Html Help Workshop** and compile it there.

What is wrong?

Update: I am trying to right click the HHP and select Compile.

Update 2: I have got the settings right now:

[image: New compiling settings]

But, there is a gotcha. If I now try to compile the project, I get another error:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017rc\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have reproduced your error because I'm always compiling outside Visual Studio (VB). I think it's the return code and totally down to hhc.exe, nothing else.

The trick is to look at the %ERRORLEVEL% after it runs. It returns "1" despite success. This could be used in a custom command to warn the user it's spurious, if the hhc.exe run is isolated from other stuff. HHC.exe is using HHA.dll. About HHA.dll info has not been published. Microsoft grant the HHA interface information under non-disclosure agreement (NDA) to approved help ISV's.

To go around this and continue you need to add `if not %errorlevel% 1 exit /B 1` in a batch file.

For further information go deeper into following threads:

- [HTMLHelp compiler works perfectly from command line but not run from a script or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150947/htmlhelp-compiler-works-perfectly-from-command-line-but-not-run-from-a-script-or)
- [HTML Help Workshop returns error after successfully compiled .chm file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012558/html-help-workshop-returns-error-after-successfully-compiled-chm-file)

Comment: Thanks. But the first link you provide is this actual discussion. :)

Comment: Corrected - excuse me.